# How to remove the background in a slick carousel?

Tags: javascript, html, css

**HTML**

```
    <div class="background">    
      <div class="slick-test">
        <div class="first-test"> Slide one</div>
        <div class="sec-test">Slide two</div>
        <div class="third-test">Slide three</div>
        <div class ="fourth-test">Slide four</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.background  {
    position: relative;
    top: 7.5%;
    left: 5%;
    right: 5%;
    background-color: rgba(187, 189, 193, 0.8); 
    background-color: rgba(187, 189, 193);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 15px;    
    width: 90%;
    height: 85%;
    padding: 30px;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.slick-test').slick({
        infinite: true,
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 3,
        variableWidth: true
      });
    });
```

However the background of the slick carousel comes over my background, how do i remove it?
I also can't seem to get a margin between each of my slides, why is that?
Thanks!

My JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/953jmndf/

Comment: Can you add a fiddle?

Comment: Just remove the background class from div  <div class="background">

Comment: I added the fiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/953jmndf/.

Comment: it doesn't help to remove the class as i want that class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**

```
.slick-test .slick-track {
    background: none !important;
}

.slick-test .slick-slide {
   background-color: #556677 !important;
   margin-right: 5px;
   padding: 3px;
}
```

[Check updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/46jpsned/2/)

Comment: Here also it only took away the background color of my background but not the background color immediately behind the slides!

Comment: @Y.Sas what is that `immediately behind`. Can you be more specific.

Comment: I have 3 layers of background around my slide and i want to get rid of my second one as i explained to @Nazar Becks. See [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/953jmndf)

Comment: But it only worked together with.slick-test div {
    background-color: none !important;
}

Comment: Sure. There are several layers in slick carousel. Carousel, track, slide. You didn't specified background for carousel and removed from track, so you're able to set background for slides

Answer (score 1):

I think you want

```
.slick-test div {
    background-color: none !important;
}
```

and make sure you cascade it finally.

On second thought, i think the css is added through the Sliders script, hence it will work for you when the css is added at end of the document before `</body>` or add the following line of JQuery

```
$('.slick-test div').css({"background-color":"transparent"});
```

next to your own code within `$(document).ready`

Comment: This didn't do anything!

Comment: You know for so many people who tried to help you , you are doing anything. Replying It doesn't work is not helping

Comment: .slick-test div {
    background-color: none !important;
} This helped together with the code of @icewind

Answer (score 0):

You want to delete immediate background of the slide.

So I have given `background:black` to your `.slick-test` and i can see that it is behind the slides. so if you give css

```
.slick-test div {
    background: none !important;
  }
```

then it will work for you.

Here is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/953jmndf/1/)

Comment: It only took away the background color of my background but not the background color immediately behind the slides!

Comment: I tried this but it didn't help, if you see your fiddle, the black background only appeared at the corners but it didn't help for the rest of the background!

Comment: so you want to remove that black background section .. right? which has already a background .

Comment: this will remove your background but along with text background, too . which you don't want to be.. right?

Comment: okay. so you got your answer from **icewind** or still having doubt?

Answer (score 0):

just remove the background-colour as;

```
.background  {
    position: relative;
    top: 7.5%;
    left: 5%;
    right: 5%;
    background: none; 
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 15px;    
    width: 90%;
    height: 85%;
    padding: 30px;
}
```

or you may keep it as `background:transparent;`

Comment: Here also i don't want to remove background color of my background but only the background color immediately behind the slides!

Comment: @Y.Sas this should work on you .
`.slick-test div { background-color: transparent !important; }`

Comment: I stillwant there to be a background to my slides and this css removed it. I also want my 3 slides on a page to have a background, however what i don't want is there to be a background directly around the 3 slides within the outer background.

Comment: @Y.Sas Is this what you are seeking for..?
`.slick-slide {
    background: red !important;
    padding: 0px 10px;
    margin: 0 1px;
}
.slick-test div { background-color: transparent !important; }
`

Comment: THis had the same effect as simply .slick-test div { background-color: transparent !important; } as the red background didn't show up. Try them both on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/953jmndf/) and you'll see what i mean

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.slick-test').slick({
          infinite: true,
          slidesToShow: 3,
          slidesToScroll: 3,
          variableWidth: true
        });
 });
```

```css
.background  {
  position: relative;
  top: 7.5%;
  left: 5%;
  right: 5%;
  background-color: rgba(187, 189, 193, 0.8); 
  background-color: rgba(187, 189, 193);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 15px; 
  width: 90%;
  height: 85%;
  padding: 30px;
}
.slick-test div { 
        background-color: transparent !important; 
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="background">    
      <div class="slick-test">
        <div class="first-test"> Slide one</div>
        <div class="sec-test">Slide two</div>
        <div class="third-test">Slide three</div>
        <div class ="fourth-test">Slide four</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I still want each slide to have a background, i only don't want there to be a a background in between the background slide and the grey background

Comment: The bavkground of .slick-test div

Comment: The body has a background color of white, the div with class background has a body color of grey, and slick-test div has a background color of white.  Those are the only 3 tags with a background color.